# Retrieve all the columns in a table if column for where clause has multiple combinations

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with data that i need to retrieve for each id and its corresponding month
every id has a specific month in which i need to use as a condition to select the records from my table. I would like to know if there is another way of me achieving this instead of having where in () with all the values , my sample is just a small snippet of the actuality data size

[image]

Is there any other way I can do this?
please may you reopen the question, i have edited it

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: Hi can the question be re opened , i just added sample data

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to do one by one. You can use IN operator with the list of ids.

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE ID IN (1,2,3....)
```

If you need to compare more than one column, then define table for combination.

```
;WITH CTE_IDMonthCombination AS
(
SELECT *
FROM 
(
VALUES
(100,1),
(101,2)
.
.
) AS t(ID, Month)
)
SELECT * FROM YourTable AS u
INNER JOIN CTE_IDMonthCombination AS c
ON c.ID = u.ID AND c.Month = u.Month;
GO
```

Or you can use TempTable, as you have mentioned in the comments.

```
SELECT *
INTO #t
FROM 
(
VALUES
(100,1),
(101,2)
.
.
) AS t(ID, Month);
GO

SELECT * FROM YourTable AS u
INNER JOIN #t AS c
ON c.ID = u.ID AND c.Month = u.Month;
GO
```

Comment: Hi thanks for ur response, my sample has lots of data and how do i do that if 2 conditions need to be tested for each record?

Comment: Thank you !! i was able to retrieve the data, question if i put my values in a temp table will i still be able to use it in the CTE_IDMonthCombination?

Comment: Yes. Instead of CTE you can use Temp table. I have updated my answer.